# JPA @OneToOne relationship deletion

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following @OneToOne relationship:

```
@Entity
public class CarUser {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "use")
    private User user;
}

@Entity
public class User {
}
```

Basically, the User is in the core model and CarUser is in an extension model. And User shouldn't know anything about CarUser (I cannot define an inverse relation on it).

The question is When I delete the User, is there anyway I can cascade delete the CarUser as well?

Comment: Do they have a relationship in the database? In how many applications will they coexist? Will `User` be in one and `CarUser` at another?

Comment: they do, CarUser will have a column referencing User, as per the JPA annotation suggested.

Comment: By relationship I mean something like a foreign key.

Comment: I'd try to use sql triggers, but judging to your model it's imposible, so, try to use some interceptors, and check what data is deleting.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, if you want to state that "User shouldn't know anything about CarUser" you can't get the persistence layer to cascade for you.

You don't necessarily need to make that statement, though - it may not be a correct design understanding. It's reasonable for entities, within the same database schema, to know about each other.

Let's put it this way -- even though (in an manufacturing/accounting system) CostingModule and LedgerModule are in different modules, they **absolutely** are expected to communicate and interact.

You can also do it with a foreign-key constraint in the database instead, or with triggers.

```
alter table CARUSER add constraint CARUSER_USER foreign key (ID) 
  references "USER" (ID) on delete cascade;
```